# Using JWT auth when running azure functons locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I wrote some Azure functions. Deployed them to Azure. Added Azure authentication so I would have to pass a bearer token to call them from azure.

Is there any way I could also require bearer authentication when running them locally from Visual studio with the Azure Function runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported. 
The reason is that the Azure authentication is happening in an IIS module which only runs in the Azure Websites service and not locally.